# Complex merge of one List<CustomType> into another

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I need to return a chronological list of alerts. The method 1 below does this.

I also need to grab alerts of a certain alert type such that if the AlertTypeID = {1,2,3,6,8,9,x}, then return those alerts by CreateDate and order them by month. 
The method 2 below does this.

Now, I need to insert the results of method 2 into the results of method 1. 
Even though the items returned by method 2 are organized by month, we only 
care about the most recent. Only the most recent subgroup item from method 2 need to follow the chronological order of the items returned from method 1. This subgroup
item will determine where the rest of the monthly items from subgroup 2 are placed.

A final requirement is that duplicates must be removed. If an item is being returned
from the subgroup alerts, it cannot also exist in the primary group alerts.

Below I have provided an illustration of the effect I am trying to achieve:

```
december alert 1 (12/23/2012)
december alert 2 (12/21/2012)
december alert 3 (12/20/2012)
december subalert 1 (12/19/2012)
december subalert 2 (12/18/2012)
december subalert 3 (12/04/2012)
december subalert 4 (12/01/2012)
december alert 4 (12/18/2012)
december alert 5 (12/12/2012)
november alert 1 (11/22/2012)
november alert 2 (11/16/2012)
november subalert 1 (11/14/2012)
november subalert 2 (11/08/2012)
november alert 3 (11/12/2012)
```

Code:

1. All Alerts By DateTime

   ```
   List<Alert> result = new List<Alert>();
   using(NeuroLabLinqDataContext dc = conn.GetContext())
   {
       IEnumerable<Alert> alerts = (from a in dc.Alerts
                                    where a.AccountID == AccountID
                                    orderby a.CreateDate descending
                                    select a).Take(40);
       result = alerts.ToList();
   }
   return result;
   ```
2. Alert Types By Month

   ```
   List<Alert> result = new List<Alert>();
   int[] alertTypes = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

   using (NeuroLabLinqDataContext dc = conn.GetContext())
   {
       IEnumerable<Alert> alerts = (from a in dc.Alerts
                                    where a.AccountID == AccountID &&
                                    alertTypes.Contains(a.AlertTypeID)
                                    orderby ((DateTime)a.CreateDate).Month ascending
                                    select a).ToList();
   }

   return result;
   ```

The grouping for the final select statement should look something like this:

```
 select new { Date = alerts.CreateDate, 
              Message = alerts.Message, 
              Type = alert.AlertTypeID, 
              RecentActivity = [if from method 2, then true] };
```

**UPDATE: Updated Method**

```
 public List<Alert> GetAlertsByAccountID(Int32 AccountID, params int[] alertTypes)
        {

            List<Alert> result = new List<Alert>();

            using (NeuroLabLinqDataContext dc = conn.GetContext())
            {
                var all = (from a in dc.Alerts
                           where a.AccountID == AccountID
                           orderby a.CreateDate descending
                           select a);

                int abc = all.Count();

                var first = all
                    .Where(a => a.AccountID == AccountID) && !alertTypes.Contains(a.AlertTypeID))
                    .OrderByDescending(a => a.CreateDate)
                    .GroupBy(a => a.CreateDate.Date)
                    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key);

                var firstKeys = first.Keys.Cast<DateTime>()
                    .ToList().OrderBy(k => k);

                var second = all
                    .Where(a => a.AccountID == AccountID) && alertTypes.Contains(a.AlertTypeID))
                    .OrderBy(a => a.CreateDate.Month)
                    .GroupBy(a => a.CreateDate.Month)
                    .ToDictionary(g => firstKeys
                        .First(k => k > g.OrderByDescending(a => a.CreateDate)
                        .FirstOrDefault().CreateDate));

                var combined = first
                    .GroupJoin(
                        second,
                        fk => fk.Key,
                        sk => sk.Key,
                        (d, l) => d.Value
                            .Union(l.SelectMany(i => i.Value).ToArray()))
                    .SelectMany(i => i);

                    result = combined.ToList(); 
            }

            return result;

        }
```

Thanks to John, I am much further along. At the moment, I am getting the following error:

> Sequence contains no matching element

at this line (I am pretty sure):

```
.First(k => k > g.OrderByDescending(a => a.CreateDate)
```

For what it is worth, here is what the data in my Alerts table looks like.

```
AlertID AccountID   CreateDate  Timestamp   AlertTypeID    Message
122 5   2008-03-11 20:48:07.983 0x00000000000128FB  9        sdfs
123 1   2008-03-11 20:48:39.957 0x00000000000128FE  8        sdfsd
124 5   2008-03-11 20:48:39.977 0x00000000000128FF  8        sdfs
125 5   2008-03-11 20:48:40.017 0x0000000000012901  8        asdfa
126 1   2008-03-12 22:57:42.160 0x00000000000130B3  4        sfsf
127 5   2008-03-12 22:57:42.337 0x00000000000130B4  4        sdfsd
128 5   2008-03-13 09:42:14.237 0x0000000000013889  4        sdfsd
129 5   2008-03-13 09:42:31.957 0x000000000001388B  4        sdfsd
130 5   2008-03-13 09:42:45.397 0x000000000001388D  5        asdfsdf
131 1   2008-03-16 14:52:17.197 0x0000000000014822  9        asdfsdf
132 1   2008-04-12 15:25:17.330 0x000000000001B582  3        sfasdf
133 5   2008-04-12 15:25:17.700 0x000000000001B583  3        dfsfds
134 6   2008-04-14 08:37:03.273 0x000000000001BD87  3        aasfsd
135 6   2008-04-14 08:37:15.270 0x000000000001BD89  3        fhfsdf
136 6   2008-04-14 08:38:45.120 0x000000000001BD8B  2        ghsdgd
137 6   2008-04-14 08:41:30.407 0x000000000001BD9A  4        fghsdfg
138 6   2008-04-14 08:42:30.800 0x000000000001BD9C  4        gfsdf
139 6   2008-04-14 08:42:43.763 0x000000000001BD9E  5        sdfsdf
140 6   2008-04-14 08:49:25.450 0x000000000001BDAA  9        sdfasdfa
141 6   2008-04-14 08:49:34.237 0x000000000001BDAC  9        sdfasdf
142 1   2008-04-14 08:50:23.380 0x000000000001BDAF  8        sdfhdfhsg
143 6   2008-04-14 08:50:23.567 0x000000000001BDB0  8        dgasdf
144 5   2008-04-14 08:50:23.690 0x000000000001BDB1  8        dgasdf
145 6   2008-04-14 08:50:23.747 0x000000000001BDB2  8         dgasdf
147 1   2008-06-24 14:22:41.183 0x00000000000222E6  14       dgasdf
148 5   2008-06-24 14:22:41.617 0x00000000000222E7  14       dgasdf
149 6   2008-06-24 14:22:41.623 0x00000000000222E8  14       dgasdf
150 1   2008-06-24 20:11:57.757 0x0000000000022AB3  13     dgasdf
151 5   2008-06-24 20:11:57.947 0x0000000000022AB4  13       dgasdf
152 6   2008-06-24 20:11:57.953 0x0000000000022AB5  13       dgasdf
153 1   2008-07-03 18:41:51.067 0x0000000000028888  14       dgasdf
154 5   2008-07-03 18:41:51.230 0x0000000000028889  14        dgasdf
155 6   2008-07-03 18:41:51.237 0x000000000002888A  14        dgasdf
156 1   2008-07-03 18:46:17.873 0x000000000002888D  14       dgasdf
157 5   2008-07-03 18:46:17.937 0x000000000002888E  14       dgasdf
158 6   2008-07-03 18:46:17.940 0x000000000002888F  14        dgasdf
```

Comment: "Group in chronological"? Do you mean group?

Comment: Seems that you need group by a criteria, and order items in resulting groups. What is this criteria? Formulate please.

Comment: Hi Abatishchev. No, I mean chronological. Both list 1 and list 2 must be in order by (DateTime) CreateDate.

Comment: Your illustration doesn't seem to have the alerts sorted by date? Or is december alert 2 supposed to be 12/21/2012 instead of 12/11/2012?

Comment: Thanks again. I'll edit my post with the group by criteria.

Comment: Hi John. Ah yes, good catch. I'll make that change now.

Comment: @CodeSherpa I'm still struggling with your criteria... you want to insert all of the alerts of the 2nd query for each month into the results of the first query based on the date of most recent alert for that month (from the 2nd query), and you do not want results that are already in the first query to be added again?  i'm getting a headache just typing that

Comment: Hi Psubsee2003. Would this help your headache? "Merge two lists, group the second list by month and insert into the first using CreateDate. Remove duplicates" :)

Comment: Can we just eliminate the subtype items from the first list?

Comment: But yes, psubsee2003, that is basically it.

Comment: @CodeSherpa ok, so the reason `december subalert 3` is ordered before `december alert 4` is because `december subalert 1` is newer.

Comment: Hi John, yes, if a subtype item exists in the second list, then it must be removed from the first.

Comment: To be clear, the first list is a strict superset of the second list right?  so if we're merging we can filter the subtypes out of the first list because we know they'll be added when we merge in the second list.

Comment: @psubsee2003, yes, that is it. december subalert 1 falls between alert 3 and alert 4.

Comment: @John, yes, good point. That makes sense. The subtypes will be introduced once the subset list is added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is breaking the two groups down into dictionaries, using the dates from the first list as the keys to the dictionary, and picking the closest key after the second list item date as the key for the second dictionary.

Once you have the two dictionaries, each using a common key value for the types and the subtypes you can just do a `GroupJoin` and `SelectMany` to get the results in a sorted list.

(* Note that the answer is based on a slightly different, earlier version of the question, I'm not going to take the time to update the answer because I think the fundamental problem is illustrated and solved in this answer already)

***update 2***
I realize the problem you're seeing with the First() call is that some of your subalert items might be newer than any other alert item which would cause your exception. I addressed that by adding a 'surrogate' key to the first dictionary using `DateTime::MaxValue`, and then I no longer filter out the subalerts from the first list, I just use `.Distinct()` on the final result to remove duplicates

Using linqpad I mocked up this question and solved it using dictionaries and `GroupJoin`

```
var all = new []{
    new {date = DateTime.Parse("2012-12-23"), type = "alert", value = 1, accountId = 333 },
    new {date = DateTime.Parse("2012-12-21"), type = "alert", value = 2, accountId = 333 },
    new {date = DateTime.Parse("2012-12-20"), type = "alert", value = 3, accountId = 333 },
    new {date = DateTime.Parse("2012-12-18"), type = "alert", value = 4, accountId = 333 },
    new {date = DateTime.Parse("2012-12-12"), type = "alert", value = 5, accountId = 333 },
    new {date = DateTime.Parse("2012-11-22"), type = "alert", value = 1, accountId = 333 },
    new {date = DateTime.Parse("2012-11-16"), type = "alert", value = 2, accountId = 333 },
    new {date = DateTime.Parse("2012-11-12"), type = "alert", value = 3, accountId = 333 },
    new {date = DateTime.Parse("2012-12-19"), type = "subalert", value = 1, accountId = 333 },
    new {date = DateTime.Parse("2012-12-18"), type = "subalert", value = 2, accountId = 333 },
    new {date = DateTime.Parse("2012-12-04"), type = "subalert", value = 3, accountId = 333 },
    new {date = DateTime.Parse("2012-12-01"), type = "subalert", value = 4, accountId = 333 },
    new {date = DateTime.Parse("2012-11-14"), type = "subalert", value = 1, accountId = 333 },
    new {date = DateTime.Parse("2012-11-08"), type = "subalert", value = 2, accountId = 333 },  
/*add*/ new {date = DateTime.Parse("2012-12-25"), type = "subalert", value = 9, accountId = 333 },  
};

var first = all
    .Where(a=>a.accountId == 333 /* removed && type != "alert" */)
    .OrderByDescending(a=>a.date)
    .GroupBy(a=>a.date.Date)
    .ToDictionary(g=>g.Key);

var firstKeys = first.Keys
    .Cast<DateTime>()
    .Union(new []{DateTime.MaxValue}) /* added this 'surrogate' key */
    .OrderBy(k=>k)
    .ToArray();

var second = all
    .Where(a=>a.accountId == 333 && a.type == "subalert")
    .OrderBy(a=>a.date.Month)
    .GroupBy(a=>a.date.Month)
    .ToDictionary(g=>firstKeys.First(k=>k > g.OrderByDescending(a=>a.date).FirstOrDefault().date));


var combined = first
    .GroupJoin(
        second,
        fk=>fk.Key,
        sk=>sk.Key,
        (d,l)=>d.Value
            .Union(l.SelectMany(i=>i.Value).ToArray()))
    .SelectMany(i=>i)
    .Distinct(); /* Added this to remove duplicates */

combined.Dump();
```

Which yields:

[image: Updated Results]

Comment: Thanks a bundle for your efforts John! And, yes, the revision of the original question was because some people found it confusing. I was trying to clarify. I am getting "Sequence contains no matching element" at the following line: " .ToDictionary(g => firstKeys.First(k => k > g.OrderByDescending(a => a.CreateDate).FirstOrDefault().CreateDate)); "  I am sure this has more to do with my data vs. your code so, I am sussing it out. I will follow up and thanks again.

Comment: @John Excellent answer... i was working on something very similar.  I think dictionaries are absolutely the best solution to this problem

Comment: @John, fantastic! The modification you added, did the trick. You, sir, are my hero!

Comment: Excellent :)  I'm sure you can tighten it up a bit and make it even better.